Find a list of events that could have impacted stock values
I'm currently working on a solution to link changes in stock values to specific events. My objective is to establish this relationship for several well-known stocks (such as Bitcoin, S&P 500, and Apple). I need to find a way to compile all the events that could affect stock values in a table format.
Do you know of any sources for this? I found something interesting on Trading Economics(https://tradingeconomics.com/calendar), but it’s a bit costly.
I looked for several sources like https://tradingeconomics.com/calendar but did not work out properly. I only found paying sources.

In one case, we used feeds of "news headlines" which we would use (count) against a database of key words to track / predict trends in stocks.
